# MPMusicPlayerController currentPlaybackTime - Milliseconds

Tags: objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there any way que retrieve from MPMusicPlayerController the elapsed time os a second in milliseconds? 
The currentPlaybackTime returns seconds and this doesn't work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The currentPlaybackTime returns seconds

Yes, but it returns those seconds *as a Double* (a TimeInterval). So it has a fractional part. It *is* giving you milliseconds; they are the stuff after the decimal point.